# Create an observable emitter on android

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, observer-pattern, rx-android

I have an android application which receives data from a websocket connection. This data is stored on a Hashmap and must be recovered from some points of the application.
I have created a "get" method that makes a Observable.just() with that data, however, I need another Observable.just() when the data is received from the websocket so the subscriber of the first observable can receive the updated data, how should I do that? Do I have to create an Observable object and always do the "just" to that observable?
How must I emit the data in order to always be received for the same subscriber (the same way as realm does)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need another Observable.just() when the data is received from the
>   websocket so the subscriber of the first observable can receive the
>   updated data, how should I do that?

Subject is what you probably you are looking for. Subject is an object that can act at the same time as `Subscriber` and `Observable`. If your get() returns `Subject#asObservable` instead of `Observable.just`, and every time you get fresh data from your websocket you call `Subject#onNext`, you will get the desired behaviour. `Subject` itself is abstract, but `RxJava` provides some concrete implementations. Please refer to the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/Subject.html) to understand the difference between them and choose the one that suits you better.

Answer (score 2):

RxJava has Hot Observables, in your case you need to use subject, to pass the emission of one observable to another.

check this unit test

```
/**
 * In this example we see how using hot observables ReplaySubject we can emit an item on broadcast to all the observers(subscribers).
 *
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
@Test
public void testHotObservableUsingReplaySubject2() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable<Long> interval = Observable.interval(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    Subject<Long, Long> publishSubject = ReplaySubject.create(1);
    interval.subscribe(publishSubject);
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    publishSubject.subscribe(System.out::println, (e) -> System.err.println(e.getMessage()), System.out::println);
}
```

You can see more examples of Hot Observables here  https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/connectable/HotObservable.java